# Play audio before hangup

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

## Is it possible to play audio before hang up?

I am streaming audio to google text to speech through a web socket.

I want to play an audio file before hang up.

I tried to send twiml like this:

```
<Response>
<Play>https://z24bwfa804c1.ngrok.io/1aec92e0-b534-11ea-9dcf-c51bcba81dbb.mp3</Play>
<Pause length="300" />
<Hangup/>
</Response>
```

With this approach, the call didn't hang up.

I also tried to change the status to completed which ended the call immediately before waiting for play end.

```
// twiml
<Response>
<Play>https://z24bwfa804c1.ngrok.io/1aec92e0-b534-11ea-9dcf-c51bcba81dbb.mp3</Play>
<Hangup/>
</Response>


await twilioClient.calls(conversationId).update(playMessageResponse);
await twilioClient.calls(conversationId).update({ status: 'completed' });
```

Should I use a timeout before changing the status or should I destroy the stream?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

When TwiML runs out, the call hangs up. Just have the `<Play>` verb and then nothing after it. The call will end once the `<Play>` is completed with the media file.

Comment: Oh my bad. I forgot to mention I am streaming audio to google speech to text service. So TwiML doesn't run out.